# Erro ao usar o Join e Count

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Olá, o erro de agora é que ele esta somando o CodSetor. Os valores seria 6 e 3, porem está vindo 6 e 6. Segue fotos e códigos.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`funcionario`.`funcionario_CodSetor`) AS total 
FROM `funcionario` 
    JOIN `setor` ON `setor`.`CodSetor` = `funcionario`.`funcionario_CodSetor` 
    JOIN `horario` ON `horario`.`horario_CodSetor` = `funcionario`.`funcionario_CodSetor` 
    JOIN `cbo` ON `cbo`.`CodCBO` = `funcionario`.`funcionario_CodCBO` 
    JOIN `familiacbo` ON `familiacbo`.`CodFamilia` = `cbo`.`cbo_CodFamilia`
WHERE `funcionario_CodEmpresa` = '32' 
GROUP BY `funcionario`.`funcionario_CodSetor`
```

Sem dar o join em horario do setor fica normal

[image: Puxando o total com horario]

[image: Puxando o total sem horario]

Comment: Está a agrupar pelo campo que está a contar? É suposto agrupar por todos os outros **exceto** esse. Tente alterar o `COUNT` para isto: `COUNT(DISTINCT funcionario.funcionario.Cod_Setor)`.

Comment: Usando o Distinct retorna apenas os valor 1 nos dois campos.